# how to display the top of the image in react native,

Tags: react-native

this is my current situation, my image looks like this

[image: actual image]

and this is my current codes

```js
<View>
      <Image
        style={{width: '100%', height: 285}}
        source={{
          uri: `${posterPath + data?.poster_path}`,
        }}
        resizeMode="cover"
      />

      <Text>{data?.title}</Text>
    </View>
```

I want my image looks like this

[image]

(this one is just example)

I know if in normal css we can using the ***object-position***, but unfortunately React Native doesn't directly support the ***object-position*** CSS property, so it's confuse me how to achieve this

Comment: Hi, I have tried many times to do this with no luck. I assume your using https://api.themoviedb.org? If that is the case you already know the height as its part of the API call. The only way I can see this working is to crop this image from the bottom to get the desired height of 285.  so if the height is 660, simply workout how much to crop, which is 375 in this case and crop that from the bottom. Only way I can do it, look at https://github.com/oguzhnatly/react-native-image-manipulator